# Mysql NodeJS reject sound query to Duplicate Databases

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

Below is a sound query to `CLONE a Database` that if executed at the command line work perfectly every time.

```
Executing (default): mysqldump 
                      --column-statistics=0 
                      -h ***.amazonaws.com 
                      -u ***
                      -p*** MyDB1 
                      --set-gtid-purged=OFF 
                          | 
                      mysql -h ***.amazonaws.com 
                      -u ***
                      -p*** MyDB2
```

NodeJS

```
  let DBname = req.body.DBname;
  var sql = `mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h ${config.global.host} -u ${config.global.user} -p${config.global.password} ${config.global.root_db_name} --set-gtid-purged=OFF | mysql -h ${config.global.host} -u ${config.global.user} -p${config.global.password}  ${DBname}  `
  db.sequelize.query(sql)
   .then( ()=> {
      console.log(`${config.global.root_db_name} copied to-> ${DBname}`)
      res.send('success')
   }).catch( err=> {
      console.log(`ERR: ${config.global.root_db_name} *FAILED* copied to-> ${DBname} ==> `+"\n\n" + err +"\n")
      res.send('fail')
   })
```

However when I embed it in to my NodeJS program it throws error:

***SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax***

Has anyone dealt with this before - all advice welcome thank you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant Node.js code snippet please?

Comment: Code is posted now

Comment: Check out the sequelize documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query. Then look at the "mysqldump" command line utility docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html. It looks like you're trying to use a method which can only execute SQL queries. "mysqldump" is not a query, it's a client utility so in this case, what you're trying to do won't work. You can try to use this to execute the CLI command: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html on your instance but idk what kind of environment you're running this in.

Comment: You are absolutely correct - how silly of me.  Thank you I posted solution below and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution came as a result of Andrew A remarks above.  I was not executing an SQL command.

here is what works

```
const shell = require('shelljs')

...

  var dump = `mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h ${config.global.host} -u ${config.global.user} -p${config.global.password} ${config.global.root_db_name} --set-gtid-purged=OFF | mysql -h ${config.global.host} -u ${config.global.user} -p${config.global.password}  ${DBname}  `

   if (shell.exec(dump).code !== 0) {
      console.log(`ERR: ${config.global.root_db_name} *FAILED* copied to-> ${DBname} `)
      res.send('fail')
    } else {
      console.log(`${config.global.root_db_name} copied to-> ${DBname}`)
      res.send('success')
    }
```